# Why can't I install Python-Markdown?

Tags: terminal, python

I've had some weird issues with my python install recently but I've usually been able to get it working. However I'm running into a really bizarre issue right now where pip is installing things that disappear. [Trying to run through this blog post](http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_markdown_syntax_color.html).

In the terminal:

```
pip install markdown
```

Everything installs correctly.

```
python -m markdown testing.md > output.html
```

It pops out the following error `/usr/bin/python: No module named markdown` which seems bizarre, since I'm running exactly what the tutorial is telling me. Then when I write `python markdown`

When I go to run the command `pip install` again it spits out the following:

```
$ pip install markdown
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): markdown in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

Any tips on how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your copy of Python 3 is not using the executable name "python". Try "python3 -m markdown" and see if that works. If it does, you can symlink python to python3, or just execute python3 when tutorials ask you to run python.

Comment: !?!?!?! Well, that's bizarre. I'm checking now.

Comment: It worked. Hallelujah!

Comment: It works. how to set python as python3?